# How can I set a runtime environment variable based on the value of another

Tags: heroku, grafana

I'm trying to deploy `grafana/grafana` Docker image on Heroku, and grafana allows you to configure everything via environment variables prefixed with `GF_`.

Heroku binds it's dyno to the docker container with a dynamic port defined at runtime via the `$PORT` environment variable.

I tried to pass the `GF_SERVER_HTTP_PORT=$PORT` via `heroku.yml` or via `heroku config:set`, without success.

If I run it locally I, it works :

```
$> docker run -ti --rm -e GF_SERVER_HTTP_PORT=1234 grafana/grafana
...
INFO[05-29|20:24:03] HTTP Server Listen logger=http.server address=0.0.0.0:1234 protocol=http subUrl= socket=
```

How can I get it to work on Heroku ?

References :

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime
- https://grafana.com/docs/installation/configuration/#using-environment-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across precisely the same problem and managed to solve it (albeit in a way that could definitely be considered "hacky").

I created a `grafana.ini` file like this:

```
[server]
http_port = <HTTP_PORT>
```

I also created a shell script which runs `sed` on that `grafana.ini` file at the time of deployment (i.e. on the Heroku server which deploys the docker image and has the `$PORT` env variable set).

```
sed -i -e 's|<HTTP_PORT>|'$PORT'|' /etc/grafana/grafana.ini
/run.sh
```

Lastly I created a Dockerfile that inherited from the standard grafana image and runs the above shell script against that ini file before running the grafana server. (Grafana sets the `ENTRYPOINT` of their image to `/run.sh`, [see here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/Dockerfile#L80)).

```
FROM grafana/grafana
ADD heroku-run.sh /
ADD grafana.ini /etc/grafana/grafana.ini
ENTRYPOINT [ "/heroku-run.sh" ]
```

After running your Heroku build/push/release commands then the end result should be a deployed Grafana service on Heroku.

The obvious added benefit to this is that all your grafana secrets can be stored in environment variables defined for your Heroku app config and then just add more `sed` commands for them in the `heroku-run.sh` (or jazz up the shell script and parameterise the variables).